# Obj-C, currency value to workable number, issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've been building a currency removal function which will work across the globe.
However a bug has come to light and unsure why.

```
+(double)removeFormatPrice:(NSString *)strPrice {

    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] 
        autorelease];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSNumber* number = [currencyFormatter numberFromString:strPrice];

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] 
        autorelease];
    NSMutableString *mstring = [NSMutableString stringWithString:strPrice];
    NSRange wholeShebang = NSMakeRange(0, [mstring length]);

    [mstring replaceOccurrencesOfString: [formatter decimalSeparator]
                             withString: @"."
                                options: 0
                                  range: wholeShebang];

    double newPrice = [mstring doubleValue];
    if (number == nil) {

        return newPrice;
    } else {
        return [number doubleValue];
    }
}
```

If I pass in 1,000.00 then it replaces the dot (period / full stop) it should just do that, but it also replaces the comma. Newprice comes out as 1. Heres my full debug...
[image]

Comment: I don't really see what's the final result you want to get. What's the expected value for 1,000.01 ? 500.25 ?

Comment: I pass in 1,000.00 (UK number format) and I should get 1000.00 or 1000, at the moment I'm getting 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
[mstring replaceOccurrencesOfString: [formatter groupingSeparator]
                             withString: @""
                                options: 0
                                  range: wholeShebang];
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that `-[NSString doubleValue]` fails to parse the string "1,00000", stopping at the comma, and returns "1". Instead, you should just format `number` according to your needs. Configure the `formatter` with the proper format you need and use it to get the final string. Don't replace any characters manually when you can rely on the framework.

EDIT: Complete code example

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSNumber* number = [currencyFormatter numberFromString:strPrice];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setPositiveFormat: @"#.00"];
NSLog(@"%@ %@", number, [formatter stringFromNumber: number]);
```

On my machine with the current locale I get:

> 1000 1000,00